# how to search for a value inside mutli dimensioanl array and return true on found else return false

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

i have just little problem here
i am trying to look for a specific ip inside the array so, **if this ip exits i want to return true else i want to return false**

however, i have tried many ways but it's not working

**i just need your help , thank in advanced**

```
function user_ip_exists($ip)
{
    // ** Get Connection
    open_handler();         

    $sql = sprintf(" SELECT `ip` FROM `answ` ");

    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    $database_ip = array();

    for ($counter=0; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); $counter++) { 

        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            $database_ip[] = $value;
        };
    }

    var_dump($database_ip);

}
// this the above var_dump

array (size=9)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
  5 => string ',127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1' (length=20) // ip address is separated with ' , '
  6 => string '' (length=0)
  7 => string '' (length=0)
  8 => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: `strpos()` will find your IP in a list of strings, for example your comma separated list.

Comment: `select ip from answ where ip = $ip`

Comment: i have tried this- but it dose not work, becuase of the coma

Comment: Where do you check for existence?

Answer (score 0):

Your `mysql_*` functions are all deprecated and you have to use either `mysqli` or any other interface like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

For searching the array you can do another loop on it:

```
foreach($database_ip as $ip)
{
  $parts = explode(",", $ip);

  if(in_array($parts, $your_ip)) return true;
}
```